# How to create a separate stack memory for std::thread?

Tags: multithreading

Nobody can tell me how to create threads in a C++ project, if instead
WinAPI ::CreateThread uses std::thread, then how can a thread be allocated a separate  stack?
I ask because I came across the fact that in the GUI, when you click on a button with the start of std::thread, the entire interface freezes!
It appears that the std::thread simply does not create a separate stack, but rather uses the GUI stack. But when using WinAPI ::CreateThread
a separate stack is created.  And when running an endless thread, the GUI is available.
I have Visual C++ MFC

Comment: std::threads have their own stacks.  Something else is wrong.  Perhaps if you post your minimal example code we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You did provide us with terrible little information, but I'm going to make a very long shot guess here: I think you might be stumped by the fact, that a `std::thread` also creates an object in the local scope, which must only be destructed *after* the thread terminated, *or* have been detached before.

Win32 `CreateThread` simply calls a different function and returns a HANDLE, which is just some "number".

I got the hunch, that if you call `std::thread::detach` on the created thread objects, it will behave as you expected, i.e., do this:

```
std::thread( YOURFUNCTION, ……).detach();
```

Of course, that looses you any form of access to the thread, managing it from the "outside".

Comment: datenwolf  Thanks for the answer!
If you have the opportunity, write to me in telegram: @iggynobad
And I’ll send you a project that will explain the essence of the problem.